# Is there something like ConstraintLayout's "dimensionRatio" property in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I wanna constraint the Image's start to parent's start, top to top, end to end when its width/height is 4/3, just like `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,3:4"` in Android Xml.

Here's my code below :

```
ConstraintLayout(
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .width(162.dp)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
            .background(color = Color.White)
            .clickable {
                //do something
            }
    ) {
        val (coverImg, title, status, date) = createRefs()

        Image(
            "some ignored properties",
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(coverImg) {
                    linkTo(start = parent.start, end = parent.end)
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                }
                .height(102.dp)//I don't want to specify its height
        )
        
        Text(...)
        AnyOtherLayout(...)
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use aspectRatio modifier in jetpack compose.

```
modifier = Modifier.aspectRatio(0.75f)
```

It takes two parameters first one is a single float value that represents that aspect ratio. Like If you want to use 3:4 you have to input 3/4f or 3/4 = .75f.

2nd one is optional by default it's false. If you send true it will consider Constraints.maxHeight first.

```
matchHeightConstraintsFirst: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 11):

The problem with using `Modifier.aspectRatio` is that it doesn't seem to be taken into account when using other constraints. Aspect ratios are actually supported by ConstraintLayout itself

Take this layout for example, we constrain one dimension as a ratio of 16:9

```
ConstraintLayout(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

    val (box) = createRefs()
    val guidelineBottom = createGuidelineFromBottom(0.1f)

    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Blue)
        .constrainAs(box) {
            linkTo(parent.start, parent.end, startMargin = 32.dp, endMargin = 32.dp)
            linkTo(parent.top, guidelineBottom)

            width = Dimension.ratio("16:9")
            height = Dimension.fillToConstraints
        }
    )
}
```

That gives us this

[image]

If we then change the offset of guidelineBottom to decrease the available height we end up with this

```
val guidelineBottom = createGuidelineFromBottom(0.9f)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, saved my day! Should have been marked as correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [**`aspectRatio`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).aspectRatio(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Boolean)) modifier:

```
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.xxx),
        "some ignored properties",
        contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
        modifier = Modifier
            .constrainAs(coverImg) {
                linkTo(start = parent.start, end = parent.end)
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
            }
            .aspectRatio(ratio = 4f/3f)
    )
```